# Unable to load kernel module 'elan_i2c_core.ko'

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I'm trying to load a custom made(sort of) module to get my touchpad to work. I downloaded "elan_i2c_core.c" and "elan_i2c.h" from github. Put them together on a folder made a "Makefile"(on the same folder) like:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m   := elan_i2c_core.o
else
KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD     := $(shell pwd)
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
%:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) $@
endif
```

When I ran `sudo make` it returned `.ko` files along with some other files but, returned some warnings too:

```
WARNING: "elan_i2c_ops" [/home/name/Templates/elan/elan_i2c_core.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "elan_smbus_ops" [/home/name/Templates/elan/elan_i2c_core.ko] undefined!
```

I tried

```
insmod elan_i2c_core.ko`
```

which returned:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module elan_i2c_core.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

The output of

```
depmod elan_i2c_core.ko`
```

was

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module elan_i2c_core.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

How do I fix it? Do I have to recompile the whole kernel from scratch or am I doing something wrong?

Additional information:

Kernel version- 4.18.0-10-generic

OS- Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: The warning and the error are some sort of common "undefined reference" error in C. The variable `elan_i2c_ops` is defined in the source [drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_i2c.c:682](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_i2c.c#L682), but it is **not exported** (`EXPORT_SYMBOL`) for modules. So you cannot use it in your module. You need to include to your module more source files for being able to build it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Is it possible to somehow hack the source file you mentioned above and add EXPORT_SYMBOL for modules or it is simply not possible? Also, what more source files do i need?

Comment: `Is it possible to somehow hack the source file you mentioned above and add EXPORT_SYMBOL for modules` - You may add needed `EXPORT_SYMBOL` to the source file, but you need to recompile it after that. Depending of nature of original `elan_i2c_core` driver (built-in or kernel module) you need to recompile either the whole kernel or a single module. `Also, what more source files do i need?` - I don't know. This is not a common way for develop custom modules by taking source files from existing ones. Just add more source files unless warnings disappear.